# Filtering and sorting xarray.Dataset by dimension coordinate column

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to switch pandas panel into xarray.Dataset

I have a dataset created form dictionary od dataframes. Each dataframe contains data for one stock. The dataframe rows are trading dates, columns are prices and indicators. Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

panel_dict = {}
panel_dict['AAPL'] = pd.DataFrame({'Open': [100, 105], 'Close': [104, 108],
                               'SMA200':[102, 110], 'RSI2': [11 , 14]},
                               index=['2017-09-01', '2017-09-02'])
panel_dict['AMZN'] = pd.DataFrame({'Open': [200, 180], 'Close': [190, 170],
                               'SMA200':[190, 190], 'RSI2': [11 , 15]},
                               index=['2017-09-01', '2017-09-02'])
panel_dict['AGN'] = pd.DataFrame({'Open': [300, 310], 'Close': [300, 310],
                               'SMA200':[250, 250], 'RSI2': [5 , 15]},
                               index=['2017-09-01', '2017-09-02'])

ds_full = xr.Dataset(panel_dict)

print(ds_full)

# selecting one day works
ds = ds_full.sel(dim_0 = '2017-09-02')
print(ds)

# filtering does not work
c = ds[ds['Close']>ds['SMA200']]
c = c[c['RSI2'] < 12.0 ]
c = c.sort_values(by = 'RSI2', ascending=True)
```

The dataset ds_full looks like:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (dim_0: 2, dim_1: 4)
Coordinates:
  * dim_0    (dim_0) object '2017-09-01' '2017-09-02'
  * dim_1    (dim_1) object 'Close' 'Open' 'RSI2' 'SMA200'
Data variables:
    AAPL     (dim_0, dim_1) int64 104 100 11 102 108 105 14 110
    AMZN     (dim_0, dim_1) int64 190 200 11 190 170 180 15 190
    AGN      (dim_0, dim_1) int64 300 300 5 250 310 310 15 250
<xarray.Dataset>
```

Selection of 1 day data with ds = ds_full.sel(dim_0 = '2017-09-02') works nice:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (dim_1: 4)
Coordinates:
    dim_0    <U10 '2017-09-02'
    * dim_1    (dim_1) object 'Close' 'Open' 'RSI2' 'SMA200'
Data variables:
     AAPL     (dim_1) int64 108 105 14 110
     AMZN     (dim_1) int64 170 180 15 190
     AGN      (dim_1) int64 310 310 15 250
```

But how can I filter some additional conditions like 'Close' > 'SMA200' or 'RSI2' < 12 ? And how to sort the result by 'RSI2' column?

In original code using pandas.panel it was like this:

```
c = ds[ds['Close']>ds['SMA200']]
c = c[c['RSI2'] < 12.0 ]
c = c.sort_values(by = 'RSI2', ascending=True)
```

Comment: Addresing ds['RSI2'] does not work, it says key error. Do I need to specify dimension dim_1 somehow?

Comment: Adding a sample `xarray.Dataset` setup would help for testing.

Comment: Provide the first few rows of pandas dataframe which you converted into xarray -- makes it easy to create a Dataset out of it

Comment: Sorry guys for badly asked question. I have rewritten the question to use sample data to be simple. I have also made sample code for testing.

Comment: Try this: `ds_full.isel((ds_full.sel(dim_1='RSI2')<12)) & (ds_full.sel(dim_1='Close')>ds_full.sel(dim_1='SMA200'))`. It gives out 1/0 (True/False) for those dimensions.

Comment: Thank you, this could be a way. However, after playing with it for a while, I have decided to return back to dataframe, which has more ways for filtering a data. So I will use xarray just to select daily snapshot (ds = ds_full.sel(dim_0 = '2017-09-02')) and then I convert it back to df (ds.to_dataframe()), where filtering is much easier.